# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть сайт на **wordpress**. Сделал отдельную страничку с калькулятором, где подключанию скрипты для получения величин, проверки и отправки данных.
Сейчас, в данном коде, который есть, при клике получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getRadioCalc1 is not defined at
>   HTMLInputElement.onclick

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<script>
  jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {

          function getRadioCalc1(val, step) {
            if (step == 0) {
              rezCalc1[1] = val;
            } else {
              rezCalc1[step + 1] = val;
            }
            if (val == 'Створок: 1') {
              imgID = '1';
            }
            if (val == 'Створок: 2') {
              imgID = '2';
            }
            if (val == 'Створок: 3') {
              imgID = '3';
            }
            if (val == 'Балконный блок') {
              imgID = '4';
            }
            $('#countCounter1').attr('src', '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/calc-sel-window-' + imgID + '.jpg');
            $('#rez1').val(rezCalc1.join(', '));
            return false;
          }

});
  })(jQuery);
</script>

<ul class="step-list">
   <li><input type="radio" class="radio" name="w-type" id="w-t-1" onclick="getRadioCalc1('Квартира',0);"><label for="w-t-1">Другое</label></li>
   <li>..</li>
   <li>..</li>
</ul>

<script>
(function( $ ) {
$(document).on('click', '.form-submit-355', function() {
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Если делать без обертки

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
});
})(jQuery);
```

то получаю ошибку изначально:

> TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function

Как это можно исправить?

P.S. Интересно, что на тестовом локальном сервере все работает даже без обертки, а на реальном уже нет, правда там разные темы установлены, но тем не менее..

Comment: Вы вызываете getRadioCalc1, а объявлена getInputCalc1.

Comment: @MAX да, спасибо за корректировку, но это было не определяющим, т.к. есть и функция `getRadioCalc1`. В описании поправил

Comment: Понятно. По jQuery, то скорее всего сама библиотека не подключена. Проверьте её наличие в html-коде, лучше в секции HEAD.

Comment: Если jQuery подключена, то js-код достаточно обрамить в $(function(){ ...тут код... }); Это типовой вариант.

Comment: @MAX ну конечно же `jQuery` подключена. Это же `wordpress`, он без нее работать в принципе не будет

Comment: @MAX а я разве не обрамил?

Comment: Лишнего добавили.

Comment: @MAX спасибо, получилось!

Comment: @MAX у меня к вам еще вопрос: почему webuiPopover через обертку подключается и функционирует нормально, а formatter (https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Formatting-User-Input-with-Specified-Pattern-formatter-js.html) точно также нет?..

Comment: `(function( $ ) {
                  $(function() {
                                      $('.pseudo-link-popover').webuiPopover({
    'trigger': 'hover',
    'width': '240',
    'placement': 'auto',
    content: function() {
      return $('#' + $(this).attr('data-src')).html();
    }
  });

$('.promo_phone_class').formatter({
    'pattern': '+7({{999}}){{999}}-{{99}}-{{99}}',
    'persistent': false
  });

              });
              })(jQuery);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лишнюю обертку убрать и все заработает

```
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict();

          function getRadioCalc1(val, step) {
            if (step == 0) {
              rezCalc1[1] = val;
            } else {
              rezCalc1[step + 1] = val;
            }
            if (val == 'Створок: 1') {
              imgID = '1';
            }
            if (val == 'Створок: 2') {
              imgID = '2';
            }
            if (val == 'Створок: 3') {
              imgID = '3';
            }
            if (val == 'Балконный блок') {
              imgID = '4';
            }
            $('#countCounter1').attr('src', '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/calc-sel-window-' + imgID + '.jpg');
            $('#rez1').val(rezCalc1.join(', '));
            return false;
          }
</script>

<ul class="step-list">
   <li><input type="radio" class="radio" name="w-type" id="w-t-1" onclick="getRadioCalc1('Квартира',0);"><label for="w-t-1">Другое</label></li>
   <li>..</li>
   <li>..</li>
</ul>

<script>
(function( $ ) {
$(document).on('click', '.form-submit-355', function() {
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```